# Removing the port number from URL

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm new to anything related to servers and am trying to deploy a django application. Today I bought a domain name for the app and am having trouble configuring it so that the base URL does not need the port number at the end of it. I have to type `www.trackthecharts.com:8001` to see the website when I only want to use `www.trackethecharts.com`. I think the problem is somewhere in my nginx, gunicorn or supervisor configuration.

## gunicorn_config.py

```
command = '/opt/myenv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/opt/myenv/top-chart-app/'
bind = '162.243.76.202:8001'
workers = 3
root@django-app:~#
```

## nginx config

```
server {
    server_name 162.243.76.202;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/myenv/static/;
    }  

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

## supervisor config

```
[program:top_chart_gunicorn]
command=/opt/myenv/bin/gunicorn -c /opt/myenv/gunicorn_config.py  djangoTopChartApp.wsgi
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor_gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor_gunicorn.out.log
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Hmm... your nginx config sends to an upstream on 127.0.0.1, but gunicorn is configured to listen on 162.243.76.202; is that intentional?  That won't work on most oses.

Comment: I agree with @IfLoop, try changing the gunicorn to 127.0.0.1, the nginx config seem fine with me, you're doing a proxy pass so it should work.

Comment: That did the trick. I changed the gunicorn file to use 127.0.0.1 and I can do everything the way I wanted. If you make an answer for that solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind to port 80, the default http port.  Then make sure in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/, your are listening on port 80.

By binding to port 80, you will not need to explicitly specify one in your url.